# CONVERT function from SQL Server to REDSHIFT

Tags: amazon-redshift

This is the code from SQL Server; I need to convert it into redshift

```
convert(decimal, LEFT(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, 3, convert(datetime, convert(varchar, Column_name))), 112), 6))
```

Any help?

Comment: please show examples for what the source and target values are (edit your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it by replacing the `convert(varchar` function with `TO_CHAR` and specifying the output format as`'YYYMMDD'`:

```
-- SQL Server original
convert(decimal, LEFT(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, 3, convert(datetime, convert(varchar, Column_name))), 112     ), 6))
-- Redshift version
convert(decimal, LEFT( TO_CHAR(        dateadd(month, 3, convert(datetime, convert(varchar, '20190102'))), 'YYYMMDD'), 6))
-- Output: 19040
```

The original uses `CONVERT` with the [SQL Server specific 3rd parameter `112` to convert the date to the format of `YYYYMMDD`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) The Redshift equivalent is [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html).